# Directing proofpoint to ms exchange

Tags: exchange-server

Do you have to set up MS exchange to trust proofpoint if proofpoint redirects your email to MS?

Don’t try anything yet.  Waiting to see what happens now that it is redirected. Wondering if I need to do something with MS or if redirect was enough

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.